# Parse XML with text between tags

Tags: java, xml, parsing, tree

i have the following scenario:

```
<xml>Text text text<a><b></b>Test text</a> text text text<c>text text</c><d><d/><xml>
```

How can i parse this xml so that i keep all the information (parse into a tree?). I need to keep the text and the sequence and position of the tags in the text.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I already tried using a java parser...i didn't manage to get it to work.

Comment: So far...what did you do?

Comment: google.com -> java parse xml On of the first results gave me this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

Comment: @Adriano : I tried to the dom4j parser...with xpath it is possible to just get the text out of the tags...but then i lose all the other information

Comment: First: WHERE and HOW you want to store them? If you need to keep that data in a tree...just keep it in the format they're and access them via DOM. Second: it's not valid XML (unclosed tags) but I suppose it's just an example you wrote here. Finally: **show us your code** and **be more specific** (see FAQ) otherwise we have to **guess** what you may need.

Comment: @Adriano: I need to store the information into a database (some of the information can then be changed: for example part of the text or the ordering of the tags). After that i have to create a text file again with a xml structure representing the new information. Tags represent formatting of the text (bold, italic, font style, but also more complex stuff)..but like you said: the xml is not wellformed or event not valid (the second <c> tag should actually be a </c> tag)...so there are no unclosed tags.

Comment: So, assuming XML will be well formed (all open tags are closed), what you have to do is to parse XML and to store it in a database. Parsing will be faster (and easier in this case) using SAX but you first need to decide the **database structure** for your data. It can't be generic because relational DBs aren't the best format to store tree data (they're just connected tables). Best **format depends on the context** (WHAT you have to store). Actually if you just need to store them...you can even use a text/xml field (using DOM each time you need to update/read it).

Comment: So you think that i can parse it with SAX?  I don't just need to store them...i need to store all the information contained in the xml into the database, so that i can to certain operations on the data. I tried various things with SAX parser...for example: if I call .getText() on the <xml> tag i just get the text without the child nodes. And if I get the child elements the information about the text and the position of the child elements in the text is missing.

Comment: @user2298830 this you even check the link i sent to you? Just in case you didn't here it goes again http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

Comment: @fGo : Yes i checked it. But i don't think, that this solves my problem? Or can you guide me into the direction, how you would use this?

Comment: @user2298830 show us the parser you tried, and i'll help you to improve it

Answer (score 0):

this isn't a well formed xml. you can't use a standard parser. 
You must write a your.

Comment: That's what i thought...how would you implement such a parser? regex?

Comment: But it has not sense, this isnt a XML, you cant parse it like it. Write what kind of data you Must save, and maybe we can choice a different data structure

Comment: My task is to parse a document with structure like the example and save all the information into a database. (After changing some information i have to create a document again)

Comment: yep, i understood, but my tip is if you create this type of documents, you can change its structure. tell me the origin of the data, maybe we can find a best way.

Comment: i'm not sure if i understand you correctly...i get this document from a customer...i do not create this document in the first place.

Comment: you wrote that you must generate this document when you edit your database

Comment: yes, but that is just the second step...this is why i need the entire information stored in the database...but my problem is to parse the xml and get all the information (tags, text, position of the tags in the text) into a database...